# .NET Framework Localized Satellite Resources

Tags: .net, localization

I have a winforms application that uses a modal popup (in this case Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox) that needs to be localized. This dialog box has a Yes/No option among other options.

I assume that changing the language/culture should change the satellite assembly that .net is looking for. However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out where to get these assemblies from?

Do I have the wrong concept of how this works? Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't it easier to use text files for localized messages?

Comment: Well the messages we have a handle on, its just the built-in text (as in this case Yes/No)

Comment: The dialog itself is already localized by the .NET Framework language pack that the user has installed.  That just takes care of the OK and Cancel button text.  What you put *in* the box is up to you to localize, there is no precooked Yes/No string.  MessageBox will be automatically localized as well.